# jQuery multiple pseudo class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, pseudo-class, css-selectors

I'd like to make the zebra effect on the first column of a table. How could I could select the first td of a tr and apply nth-child(2n) on it?

Answer (score 2):

The `:nth-child()` pseudo-class goes to the `tr`, and the `:first-child` pseudo-class to the `td`:

```
$('tr:nth-child(2n) td:first-child').css('background-color', '#ccc');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `nth-child(2n)` to the `<tr>` and then use `:first-child` to only select the first `<td>`. Check it out here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/WtLek/